# Caching web routes with forced url in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, caching, routes

I'm running a laravel project behind a reversed proxy which is why I need to force the root url and scheme:

```
URL::forceRootUrl($proxy_url);
URL::forceScheme($proxy_schema);
```

I've added this to the top of my `/routes/web.php` and it's working fine until I run:

```
php artisan optimize
```

It caches the routes in `/bootstrap/cache` **without** the forced url and scheme, so now all my urls are pointing to the wrong root url.

I've tried to move the code to `/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php` (both `register` and `boot`) in order to make it take effect when caching the routes but no luck.

I have to manually delete the routes cache file in `/bootstrap/cache` to make my routes work again.

Have do I make it take effect when caching the routes?

Edit:
I have also tried to create a global middleware where I do the force url and schema. Again it works fine before caching the routes, but when running `php artisan optimize` the routes are once again incorrect.

Comment: which laravel version are you using?

Comment: Im using the current newest version 5.8

Answer (score 9, accepted):

php artisan optimize removed since laravel 5.6  ([source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/upgrade), [source2](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-5-6-removes-artisan-optimize))

[image]

Comment: Keep in mind that the `php artisan route:cache` [still exists](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/controllers#route-caching), and if the OP is using it, likely the problem will remain. I'd suggest to follow @PtrTon suggestion using `TrustProxies` and fix the root problem.

Answer (score 7):

Using `URL::forceRootUrl` and `URL::forceScheme` seems like a work-around for working with reverse proxies. The clean solution for it would be to add a trusted proxies in your configuration. [This post](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#configuring-trusted-proxies) explains the feature in full. But it comes down to:

1. Use the `App\Http\Middleware\TrustProxies` middleware
2. Edit the middleware `$proxies` property with the IP(s) of your load balancer

```
    protected $proxies = [
        '192.168.1.1',
        '192.168.1.2',
    ];
```

3. Remove the following code from `/routes/web.php`

```
URL::forceRootUrl($proxy_url);
URL::forceScheme($proxy_schema);
```